# UITableView only sending data to Detail View Controller on Second Try

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, storyboard, segue

Hey there I have been working on a transit app for some time and have been stuck with this issue for a while now.

I am using iOS 5 and a storyboard. Basically I have a UITableView that displays favorite bus stop locations, when a user selects a row I use:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Favorite *favorite = [self.favoriteItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    stopString = favorite.title;
    routeString = favorite.subtitle;
}
```

With the stop and route information of the cell the user chose I then prepare for a segue that corresponds to a segue on my storyboard, pushing a detail view controller that uses the stop name and route name to display times from a plist.

I am fairly new to Objective C and iOS so I am using a segue that my friend told me would work, however, it might be the problem. The segue looks like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)])
    {
        [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];
    }
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelection:)])
    {
        NSString *route = routeString;
        NSDictionary *selection1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:route, @"route", stopString, @"stop", nil];
        [destination setValue:selection1 forKey:@"selection"];
    }
}
```

After the segue in my DetailViewController I grab the stop and route information in the view DidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    route = [selection objectForKey:@"route"];
    stopName = [selection objectForKey:@"stop"];

    NSLog(@"stopName: %@", stopName);
    NSLog(@"routeName: %@", route);
}
```

Here is where my problems arise. When I run the simulator and click on an a cell in my table view, I am pushed to the DVC, however, the stopName and routeName are both null, so no information was sent or received. BUT, if I go back to the table and click another cell, the routeName and stopName are filled with the information that should have sent the first time I clicked a cell. If I continue this process it continues to send the information for the cell tapped previously, not currently.

So basically information is sending but only after I go through the segue twice. Obviously I want it to send the information and receive it the first time, but it is delayed and driving me nuts. I appreciate any help someone can give me as I have been searching the internet for days now trying to fix this issue, thank you so much in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prepareForSegue:` is being called before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  This is why the values you see always are lagging behind.

The better solution is to get the stopString and routeString values in your `prepareForSegue:` method (and not use `didSelectRowForIndexPath:` at all).  The key to doing this is to realize that the `sender` parameter value being passed to `prepareForSegue:` is the UITableViewCell that was tapped.  You can use the UITableView method `indexPathForCell` to get the cell's indexPath in your table, and then use that to look up the data in your `favoriteItems` array.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];   
    Favorite *favorite = [self.favoriteItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    stopString = favorite.title;
    routeString = favorite.subtitle;

    UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)])
    {
        [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];
    }
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelection:)])
    {
        NSString *route = routeString;
        NSDictionary *selection1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:route, @"route", stopString, @"stop", nil];
        [destination setValue:selection1 forKey:@"selection"];
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer. was looking for this allover SO

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are NOT connecting the segue to the next view controller to the tableView CELL directly. Connect to the whole UITableViewController / UIViewController (whichever you are using) and give a name, say "segueNameInStoryboard".

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Favorite *favorite = [self.favoriteItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    stopString = favorite.title;
    routeString = favorite.subtitle;

    /* add this line */
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueNameInStoryboard" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueNameInStoryboard"])
    {    
        UIViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        nextViewController.delegate = self;

        NSDictionary *selection1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:routeString, @"route", stopString, @"stop", nil];
        nextViewController.selection = selection1;
    }
}
```