# UITableView reloads data only on second attempt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have two UITableView controllers, A and B. If the user clicks on cell one of table A, the user is redirected to table B with 10 cells. If the user clicks on cell two of table A, the user is redirected to table B with 1 cell.

**Theory**

- Click 1: Table A, Row One ---> Table B with 10 cells (layout with associated URLs)
- Click 2: Table A, Row Two ---> Table B with 1 cell (layout with associated URL)

The bug I am observing is this:
When first clicking on the first row of Table A, and clicking on the second row of Table A thereafter, table B is displayed with 10 cells. 9 of those cells are not clickable, and the first cell is identical with the only cell that should be displayed (but with the layout of the other 9 not clickable cells). Only when clicking the back button and clicking onto the second row of table A again the 1 cell is displayed properly in table B.

**Practice**

- Click 1: Table A, Row One ---> Table B with 0 cells
- Click 2: Table A, Row One ---> Table B with 10 cells (layout with
  associated URLs)
- Click 3: Table A, Row Two ---> Table B with 10 cells
  (layout only; 1st cell with associated URL)
- Click 4: Table A, Row Two ---> Table B with 1 cell (layout with associated URL)

I believe someone else experienced the same bug ([UITableView only sending data to Detail View Controller on Second Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980738/uitableview-only-sending-data-to-detail-view-controller-on-second-try)). However, the feedback is for Objective C so I don't understand what to do.

The code for my segue is:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "viewOverviewArticle" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let recentObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            let controller =  segue.destinationViewController as! ArticleAnalysis
            controller.analysisItem = recentObject
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that I indeed experience the same problem as [UITableView only sending data to Detail View Controller on Second Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980738/uitableview-only-sending-data-to-detail-view-controller-on-second-try), my question boils down to this:

How can I make sure the segue that is triggered when clicking onto a row in my table has up-to-date data?

Comment: Are you manually triggering the segues?

Comment: My storyboard has a segue that is named "viewOverviewArticle", and the code I use to configure the segue is pasted above in its entirety

Comment: The segue is triggered through user interaction by clicking manually onto a certain row in the table

Comment: Do you have the same dataSource object for both tableViews? This could cause the error with the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method returning the table A's tableView's data on the first load before that data is updated to reflect what should be on table B

Comment: I set the data source to self. I refer to each table as tableView and there is no outlet connected to either table. How would you recommend I set the data source for each table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the command for deleting the old saved data from viewWillAppear to viewWillDisappear - that fixed the bug.